# SQL & CASE STATEMENT

Tags: mysql, sql

The below query fails to run obviously due to incorrect syntax/methodology of writing.

Could someone please help me correct this?

I'm trying to do the  the below,

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.O_UPDATE,0) AS O_UP, COALESCE(t2.O_READ,0) AS O_RE, COALESCE(t3.OR_READ,0) AS OR_RD, COALESCE(t4.OR_U_READ,0) AS OR_U_RD 
 from the inner SELECT statements & then pass them to a CASE statement to set values for various variables ( This I think is evident from the code logic) 

SELECT TV_DATE, 
        CASE
            WHEN t5.O_UP BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN O_WT=5
            WHEN t5.O_RE BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN O_RD_WT = 6
            WHEN t5.OR_RD BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN 5 OR_RD_WT = 4
            WHEN t5.OR_U_RD BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN  OR_U_RD_WT = 3
            ELSE O_WT=0, O_RD_WT=0,OR_RD_WT=0, OR_U_RD_WT=0
FROM
    (
        SELECT COALESCE(t1.O_UPDATE,0) AS O_UP, COALESCE(t2.O_READ,0) AS O_RE, COALESCE(t3.OR_READ,0) AS OR_RD, COALESCE(t4.OR_U_READ,0) AS OR_U_RD FROM
        (SELECT SUM(TV_R_U_COUNT) as O_UPDATE from TVS where TV_T_NAME='abcd' AND TV_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND TV_R_U='U' AND TV_I_NAME LIKE 'w1%we%' AND TV_I_NAME like 'we%avd%') t1,
        (SELECT SUM(TV_R_U_COUNT) as O_READ from TVS where TV_T_NAME='abcd' AND TV_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND TV_R_U='X' AND TV_I_NAME LIKE 'w1%we%' AND TV_I_NAME like 'er%dfr%') t2,
        (SELECT SUM(TV_R_U_COUNT) as OR_READ from TVS where TV_T_NAME='abcd' AND TV_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND TV_R_U='X' AND TV_I_NAME LIKE 'w1%we%' AND TV_I_NAME like 'cv%dfr%' AND TV_I_NAME NOT LIKE 'dsf%er%') t3,
        (SELECT SUM(TV_R_U_COUNT) as OR_U_READ from TVS where TV_T_NAME='abcd' AND TV_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND TV_R_U='X' AND TV_I_NAME LIKE 'w1%we%' AND TV_I_NAME like 'ad%asd%ere') t4
    ) t5 TVS 
GROUP BY TV_DATE

+-------------+------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
|    DATE     | O_WT | O_RD_WT | OR_RD_WT | OR_U_RD_WT | OR_U_RD_WT |
+-------------+------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| 2015-01-01  |    5 |       6 |        4 |          3 |          0 |
| 2015-01-02  |    5 |       0 |        0 |          3 |          0 |
| 2015-01-03  |    5 |       0 |        0 |          0 |          0 |
| 2015-01-04  |    5 |       6 |        4 |          0 |          0 |
| 2015-01-05  |    5 |       0 |        0 |          3 |          0 |
+-------------+------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

I'd appreciate any help please.

Comment: Where exactly is the error? What is the actual error you get?

Comment: Why GROUP BY but no aggregate functions?

Comment: BTW, case expression - not case statement...

Comment: @jarlh sometimes group by is used to be lazy in typing extra columns knowing they come along for the ride anyway even with an aggregate function. It all comes down to pain for those eyes that follow, including those of the original programmer

Comment: @DrewPierce, yes, I know, that's why I keep asking this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use separate `case` statement statement.try this

```
SELECT TV_DATE, 
        CASE WHEN t5.O_UP BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN O_WT=5 ELSE O_WT=0 END as O_WT,
        CASE WHEN t5.O_RE BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN O_RD_WT = 6 ELSE O_RD_WT=0 END as O_RD_WT,
        CASE WHEN t5.OR_RD BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN 5 OR_RD_WT = 4 ELSE OR_RD_WT=0 END as OR_RD_WT,
        CASE WHEN t5.OR_U_RD BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN  OR_U_RD_WT = 3 ELSE OR_U_RD_WT=0 END as OR_U_RD_WT
```

your whole query will go like this

```
SELECT TV_DATE, 
        CASE WHEN t5.O_UP BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN O_WT=5 ELSE O_WT=0 END as O_WT,
            CASE WHEN t5.O_RE BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN O_RD_WT = 6 ELSE O_RD_WT=0 END as O_RD_WT,
            CASE WHEN t5.OR_RD BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN 5 OR_RD_WT = 4 ELSE OR_RD_WT=0 END as OR_RD_WT,
            CASE WHEN t5.OR_U_RD BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN  OR_U_RD_WT = 3 ELSE OR_U_RD_WT=0 END as OR_U_RD_WT 
FROM
    (
        SELECT COALESCE(t1.O_UPDATE,0) AS O_UP, COALESCE(t2.O_READ,0) AS O_RE, COALESCE(t3.OR_READ,0) AS OR_RD, COALESCE(t4.OR_U_READ,0) AS OR_U_RD FROM
        (SELECT SUM(TV_R_U_COUNT) as O_UPDATE from TVS where TV_T_NAME='abcd' AND TV_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND TV_R_U='U' AND TV_I_NAME LIKE 'w1%we%' AND TV_I_NAME like 'we%avd%') t1,
        (SELECT SUM(TV_R_U_COUNT) as O_READ from TVS where TV_T_NAME='abcd' AND TV_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND TV_R_U='X' AND TV_I_NAME LIKE 'w1%we%' AND TV_I_NAME like 'er%dfr%') t2,
        (SELECT SUM(TV_R_U_COUNT) as OR_READ from TVS where TV_T_NAME='abcd' AND TV_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND TV_R_U='X' AND TV_I_NAME LIKE 'w1%we%' AND TV_I_NAME like 'cv%dfr%' AND TV_I_NAME NOT LIKE 'dsf%er%') t3,
        (SELECT SUM(TV_R_U_COUNT) as OR_U_READ from TVS where TV_T_NAME='abcd' AND TV_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND TV_R_U='X' AND TV_I_NAME LIKE 'w1%we%' AND TV_I_NAME like 'ad%asd%ere') t4
    ) t5 TVS
```

Comment: Hello Ameya - Thank you very much for this. Could you please help me add date as well to the output? As represented int he output, I need the value of O_WT,  O_RD_WT,  OR_RD_WT, OR_U_RD_WT &  OR_U_RD_WT  for each day. I'm guessing the innermost SELECT queries have to be modified to include date. I'm not sure how to fir that in the full picture.